# Applying velocity to a SKSpriteNode subclass & trouble with Expected Declaration Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm currently working on my first iPhone game and I have a SKSpriteNode subclass `Alien` (which is also an abstract class) that will later be inherited by a class `normAlien`. Even with Apple's docs, I've been having a lot of trouble figuring out class initialization and inheritance in Swift. Here is the code for both classes:

```
//Generic alien type: a blue-print of sorts
class Alien:SKSpriteNode{

    static func normalizeVector(vector:CGVector) -> CGVector{
        let len = sqrt(vector.dx * vector.dx + vector.dy * vector.dy)
        return CGVector(dx:vector.dx / len, dy:vector.dy / len)
    }

    func motion(velocity:CGVector, multiplier:CGFloat){
        //Alien.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocity.dx * multiplier //Why no work?
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocity.dx * multiplier
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = velocity.dy * multiplier
    }

    let velocityVector:CGVector
    let startPos:CGPoint

    init(texture:SKTexture, startPosition startPos:CGPoint,moveSpeed: CGFloat,velocityVector:CGVector){

        self.velocityVector = Alien.normalizeVector(velocityVector)
        self.startPos = startPos

        //Makes sure the SKSpriteNode is initialized before modifying its properties
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

        //PhysicsBody is a property of super so super.init must be called first (init SKSpriteNode)
        self.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Alien //physicsBody?. is optional chaining?
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 //Do I need this? or jsut use in laser class
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Laser
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        //Motion
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocityVector.dx * moveSpeed
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = velocityVector.dy * moveSpeed

        //self.velocityVector = normalizeVector(velocityVector)
        self.position = startPos
    }

    //Alien.motion(self.velocityVector, moveSpeed)

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

As well as:

```
class normAlien:Alien{

    static let alienImage = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/alien.png")
    //alienImage.setScale(0.2)

    init(startPos:CGPoint,speed: CGFloat){
        super.init(texture:normAlien.alienImage, startPosition: startPos, moveSpeed:speed,velocityVector:CGVector(dx: 1,dy: 0))
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I have a function:

```
func buildAlien(){
     let aAlien = normAlien(startPos:CGPoint(x:0,y:size.height/2), speed:100)
     addChild(aAlien)
}
```

that that instantiates `normAlien` within `didMoveToView` (This function is just called within a `SKAction.repeatActionForever`). For some reason each sprite created fails to move. I'm confused because they do move if I use a `SKAction.moveTo` so I must not understand something about applying velocity.

On top of this, I'm confused as to why I receive the error: `Expected declaration`when I attempt to manipulate the `normAliens` texture with `alienImage.setScale(0.2)` and also when I try to call an internal method on the class: `Alien.motion(self.velocityVector, moveSpeed)`? I would think that calling this method inside the class would cause every instance I make to have it called- making them potentially move.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: One problem is that `Alien` refers to a class but `motion` is an instance method.  That is, it needs to be applied to a specific object.  So, you could say `self.motion(...)` if you were inside some other instance method.

Comment: For `setScale`, it doesn't seem to exist for a `SKTexture`.  Also, you're trying to execute it outside of any method.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks so much for the help, I guess if I made motion `static` it would apply to `Alien`, but then I wouldn't be able to reference `self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocity.dx * multiplier` as `self` wouldn't apply anymore? With `setScale` I just realized that you're right- I should have applied it to the SKSpriteNode, but when I do with the line `normAlien.setScale(0.2)` inside `normAlien` I again get the error: `Expected Declaration`. What does this mean exactly?? Also, any idea why applying this velocity wouldn't make the sprite move? I seem to be missing something in my code.

Comment: Same basic problem.  `setScale` works on an object but `normAlien` is a class.